# How to make control Scalable by Mouse?

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to code a simple slideshow program.
I have a class named SlideShowText.
I want it to be scalable by mouse like scaling the control in Visual Studio.
I want it to have dotted borders.
Any help?
(I didn't try anything since im such a noob)

Comment: Did you try searching at least? - [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870285/how-to-make-an-object-scalable-while-rendered-in-a-form?rq=1) - You will only need the lower left corner, I'd say..

Comment: WinForms is not the best choice for that... Does your form has only text and borders. If so, then you might draw yourself exactly like you want...

Comment: That kind of control and behavior is easier to do in WPF if some want to zoom other controls like button, scroll bars... One can easily embed WPF controls in a WinForms application.

Comment: Additional to options proposed by Taw and Alexander Petrov, you also can hanlde `WM_NCHITTEST` for your control and perform resizing. For example take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19670447/3110834) example which is for `Form` but can simply apply to controls even without creating an inherited control.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems? - If you are happy with an answer, please consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make any control sizeable with the mouse, overriding its `CreateParams` property.

For example

```
class SizeableRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            const int WS_SIZEBOX = 0x40000;
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= WS_SIZEBOX;
            return cp;
        }
    }
}

class SizeablePictureBox : PictureBox
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            const int WS_SIZEBOX = 0x40000;    
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= WS_SIZEBOX;    
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

Now they have a thick border and can be resized with the mouse.

The image scale in the `SizeablePictureBox` will change automatically, if you set the `ImageLayout.Zoom` parameter.

```
var pictureBox = new SizeablePictureBox { Parent = this, Width = 500, Height = 500 };
pictureBox.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;
pictureBox.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("pic.jpg");
```

To change the text scale in the `TextBox` you have to manually calculate the aspect ratio and change the font size. Or you can try to change the value of `ZoomFactor` property.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Resizer control:

```
public partial class Resizer : Control
{
    public Resizer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(12, 12);
    }

    public Control control { get; set; }
    Point mDown = Point.Empty;

    public Resizer(Control ctl) 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        control = ctl;
        Size = new System.Drawing.Size(12, 12);
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
    {
        base.OnLayout(levent);
        if (control != null)
        {
            BackColor = Color.DarkOrange;
            Location = new Point(control.Width - Size.Width, 
                                 control.Height - Size.Height);
            Parent = control;
            BringToFront();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mDown = e.Location;
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button.HasFlag(MouseButtons.Left))
        {
            Left += -(mDown.X - e.X);
            Top += -(mDown.Y - e.Y);
            control.Size = new Size(Right, Bottom);
        }
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }
}
```

After adding it to the project you can use it maybe like this:

```
Resizer rz = null;

private void pictureBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rz == null) rz = new Resizer(pictureBox1);  else rz.Show();
}
```

Result:

[image]